# Empty value of GET parameter in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, parameters, get

I'm using zend framework in my site. URI address one of the page is:
http://mysite.com/controller/action/no/123/date//email//

I expect to obtain the next GET parameters and values:

```
no=>123
date=>
email=>
```

It's true on localhost but on the web hosting on obtained:

```
no=>123
date=>email
```

It looks like empty values was missed. What can be a reason for this and how I can it fix?

Answer (score 0):

You have issue there is routes have done like first is key and next is value so, in your url have two blank space. change in url something line below.

try like this

http://mysite.com/controller/action/no/123/date/email/

Comment: thanks for answer, but i need uri like http://mysite.com/controller/action/no/123/date//email// (with empty values) but obtained like this http://mysite.com/controller/action/no/123/date/email/ (without empty values and with shift key to value)

Comment: check like this below you can make modifications


echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'info'), null, true);
// Output: user/info
 
// Using encode:
echo $this->url(
    array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'info', 'username' => 'John Doe'), null, true, false
);
// Output: user/info/username/John Doe
 
echo $this->url(
    array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'info', 'username' => 'John Doe'), null, true, false
);
// Output: user/info/username/John+Doe

Comment: may be I did not describe problem clearly. It is not zend code problem. When i write in browser address line mysite.com/controller/action/no/123/date//email// with $this->getRequest()->getParams() I obtain only 2 pairs key=>value, not 3. And the question why empty values was missed and what I should to do for save it?